# DAX variable defined by VAR produces different results then CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi, dax

Why sometimes do we need to use CALCULATE(...) instead of previously defined variable, which is `x=CALCULATE(...)`?

```
Measure Rank = 
VAR x = SUM ( Table1[Value] )

RETURN
    RANKX (
        ALL ( 'Table1'[Category] ),
        CALCULATE (SUM ( Table1[Value] )) -- here. why not CALCULATE( x )
    )
```

If we use `CALCULATE(x)` we will get 1 all across the visual.

Is there any golden rule for using named variables? I mean generalization like:

- for ordinary SUM use named VAR
- but with SUM**X** or Any**X** functions always use CALCULATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this formula, the variable X is evaluated before performing the RANKX. It means the value of the variable X is the same for all Categories of Table1, meaning the RANKX will return 1 all categories.

The Calculate function will pass the filter context to the sum, meaning the sum will be evaluated based on the filtering of table1 per category. Thanks to that each category will have its own sum and the Rankx will be able to return a ranking based on the sum of each category.

Comment: Is there any golden rule for using named variables? Like with ordinary SUM use named VAR but with SUMX or AggX functions only CALCULATE?

Comment: Regarding naming convention, there is no golden rule for DAX variable naming convention. you can use a prefix with _ (1 underscore) or __ (double underscore). Regarding structure of measure, you need to follow the structure VAR xxx VAR xxx .... RETURN xxx

Comment: You miss understood me. I am not asking about naming convention but USING rule of defined variables. It seams that we cannot use a priori defined variables in AggX function. I think we may do it in a different way `m = AggX ( tbl, var MyVar = [measure] return MyVar)`. I am asking about rule in which cases we can use VAR in the beginning of the function and refer to it later.